# Rails Ruby Geometry Gem breaking in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geometry, point

running `Geometry::Point.new(1,1)` in development goes fine meanwhile in my production server it gives `uninitialized constant MyControllerController::Geometry`

on my production server, I've checked this:
`bundle exec bundle show geometry` returns 
`/path_to_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/geometry-6.2`

`bundle exec bundle show ruby-geometry` got
`/path_to_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ruby-geometry-0.0.5`

in dev , even `Point(1,1)` works , with no need of module and 'new', which breaks in production too. returning: `NameError: uninitialized constant Point`

I've tried `require 'geometry'` and `include Geometry`, but both till fails

can someone help me plz?

Comment: try `::Geometry::Point.new(1,1)`

Comment: nothing \= 
`NameError (uninitialized constant Geometry):`

Comment: Have you tried `require 'geometry'`? Note the lowercase g

Comment: on my controller? yes

Comment: eddited my question... srry ;. thank you :d

Comment: No problem, but thought that might solve it for you, too bad!

Comment: after some changes... when restarted unicorn `...dependencies.rb:228:in 'require': No such file to load -- geometry (LoadError)`

Comment: put all my logic in model, and then...

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'Point') for MyModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days trying to solve this problem the answer was in reboot the machine... reset only the nginx and unicorn do not worked... but when I do reboot the VPS, it started working ...

How did we find out?
Searching about we have run into [Pow not loading gem properly while rails s works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801200/pow-not-loading-gem-properly-while-rails-s-works)
I'm Using Ubuntu with nginx and unicorn, nothing to see with Pow ... whatever it gave some light... for no reason we decided reboot the VPS ... and it worked.

Thank you all who helped me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you you put `ruby-geometry` gem into your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'ruby-geometry', require: 'geometry'
```

I probably should emphasize it even more in README file of the gem.

Comment: Its already there... should I `require 'geometry'` or not in files I used Point?
when I use, unicorn even start the server, when I do not, the problem is specific with Point `NoMethodError (undefined method 'Point') for MyModel` but the server runs...

Comment: `require 'geometry'` in Gemfile should be enough. Can you reproduce this error in an empty Rails app? If you can, you could push an empty project to github and I would investigate and fix the problem then.

Comment: as I said this errors is just happening in production :S

Comment: "only in production" -- does it depend on type of server (unicorn) or system gems on production server? This is what we are to figure out. Then we'll be able to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54504/discussion-between-mauro-dias-and-daniel-vartanov).